# Record Espresso Test For Two InstantApp Modules

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instant-apps

PROBLEM: An instantapp activity from one module (`base`) calls activity from another module (`my_feature`). Both should be tested using '*Record Espresso Test*' in Android Studio.

RESEARCH: Espresso-generated code for **non-instant** application has `R.id.component` references on both activities. In an **instant-app** generated code only references from the first module are in the scope. So you can't access components from an activity of another module.

QUESTION: How to **test inter-module actions** in Espresso?

Opened a bug issue at Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/4/issues/77502630

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Answer (score 0):

As far as there is *no movement on the bug*, I've resulted with a workaround, using **Appium**. It can be *integrated into Android Studio tests*, though a parrallel Appium window should be kept open in your system.

Appium is a higher-level testing framework on base of Selenium Web Driver. So it doesn't use Android Project Resources like Espresso and **allows cross-feature testing**. Moreover it **allows cross-app testing** and **testing your app integractions with Android System** messaging, settings, power, cellular signal and other features.

Here is a detailed instruction on how to [setup Appium with Android Studio testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961382/1112963).